# Software to solve semidefinite programs

Tags: math

I'm looking for software to solve a particular semidefinite program.

The constraints are specified as a set of linear constraints on pairwise products of the components of some vector (x<sub>i</sub>)<sub>i</sub> ∈ ℝ<sup>n</sup>:

[image: Semidefinite Program Form]

I'm hoping to find software which accepts the problem in this format. I know there are alternate ways of expressing SDP's, but I'm hoping to avoid writing a program to translate between formats.

Comment: What operating system do you need it for? What is your price constraint?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for deleting my answer. Let me summarize it. Any SDP solver can solve the program the OP is interested in, *as is*. It is not a "particular" semidefinite program, but rather the standard normal form of an SDP. The only difference is that the SDP solver finds a PSD matrix, and to get the vectors $x^i$ you need an extra step of Cholesky decomposition at the end.

Comment: I'm also not sure that this is the correct site to answer the question, given the apparent answer.

Comment: Did you look at the usual optimization programs like CPLEX or GUROBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your semidefinite program is already in standard form. What you describe is known as a *vector program*. Vector programs are equivalent to semidefinite programs. If instead of *x<sup>i</sup>*·*x<sup>j</sup>* you write *X*<sub>*i*,*j*</sub> and add the condition that *X* be positive semidefinite then the two programs are equivalent. Therefore you can use any SDP solver to solve your program. Given the positive semidefinite matrix *X*, you can find vectors *x<sup>i</sup>* such that *x<sup>i</sup>*·*x<sup>j</sup>* = *X*<sub>*i*,*j*</sub> using [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), which is readily available in many libraries and mathematical software, and might even be supported by some SDP solvers.

Comment: I have a large text file with variables $x^i$ like I said. The constraints are written in this form. Sometimes they appear like this $(x_1 + x_2)x_3 <= 0$ What I'm looking for is a program that will accept my problem statement with minimal changes, otherwise I will have to rewrite the problem as you say, looking for instances of $x_i x_j$ and substituting $X_{ij}$

Comment: SDP solvers don't typically accept inputs in this way, see for example this common format: http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/sdpa_format.txt. So you'd have the same problem even if your program was stated in terms of *Xij*'s.